# Visual Paradigm: Invalid Syntax Highlighting without acutal syntax mistake (as far as I can see)

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I think I have encountered an error message that is not necessarily valid or helpful. If it is valid, please tell me what the mistake I encounter is triggered by.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not follows UML notation and you exchanged the parameter and its type, your operations must be

- `create(entity : E) : Result<E>`
- `create(entities : iterable<E>) : ResultCollection<E>`

Your `create(E : entity) : Result<E>` was accepted 'syntactically' because the var can be *E* and its type *entity*, but in the second case the var name `iterable<E>` is illegal and the tool refuses that.

From [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §9.6.4 page 117 and 118 :

> If shown in a diagram, an Operation is shown as a text string of the form:
>
> `[<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’`
>         `[‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’]`
>         `[‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’ <oper-property>]* ‘}’]]`
>
> and `<parameter-list>` is a list of Parameters of the Operation in the following format:
>
> `<parameter-list> ::= <parameter> [‘,’<parameter>]*`

and § 9.4.4 page 110 :

> `<parameter> ::= [<direction>] <parameter-name> ’:’ <type-expression>`
>        `[’[’<multiplicity-range>’]’] [’=’ <default>]`
>        `[’{’ <parm-property> [’,’ <parm-property>]* ’}’]`

So it must be `<parameter-name> ’:’ <type-expression>` rather than `<type-expression> ’:’ <parameter-name>` as you did

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was more than tired at that point, anyway I will leave this post here just in case anyone else stumbles over this issue as well

Comment: @FynnMehrens, yes sure, no one asked you to remove it